# subtract a value form the mysql database where my subtrahend is from the value of a text box

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Hi I am new to c# and here is the problem, I have a column named "no_of_available_item". I need to get its value subtracted by the value from a text box and their difference will be input again in my column no_of_available_item, this code does not work , any help ?thank so much in advance.

```
public void Borrow_select(int intBorrow)
    {
        string str_Query;
        str_Query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_item  WHERE id = ' + myID + '";
        DbCmd = new MySqlCommand(str_Query, DbCn);
        DbRead = DbCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (DbRead.Read())
        {
            no_of_available_item = Convert.ToInt16( DbRead["no_of_available_item"]);
            int_result = no_of_available_item - intBorrow;

            str_Query = "UPDATE tbl_item SET no_of_available_item = '" + int_result + "' WHERE id = '" + myID + "'";              
        }  
    }
```

Comment: my code doesn't work , dont know whats my mistake

Comment: Security Note: assuming myID is a string, you are open to a SQL injection attack. Using [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) avoids [this disaster](http://bobby-tables.com/) as well as making formatting easier..

Answer (score 1):

you get the current value, an modify thw sql commanf, but you nee execute it again:

```
public void Borrow_select(int intBorrow)
{
    string str_Query;
    str_Query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_item  WHERE id = ' + myID + '";
    DbCmd = new MySqlCommand(str_Query, DbCn);
    DbCn.Open();
    DbRead = DbCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (DbRead.Read())
    {
        no_of_available_item = Convert.ToInt16(DbRead["no_of_available_item"]);
        int_result = no_of_available_item - intBorrow;

        str_Query = "UPDATE tbl_item SET no_of_available_item = '" + int_result + "' WHERE id = '" + myID + "'";
    }
    DbCmd = new MySqlCommand(str_Query, DbCn);
    DbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DbCn.Close();
}
```

Or better, let the server do two things together:

```
public void Borrow_select(int intBorrow)
{
    string str_Query;
    str_Query = "UPDATE tbl_item SET no_of_available_item = no_of_available_item +" + int_result + " WHERE id = '" + myID + "'";
    DbCmd = new MySqlCommand(str_Query, DbCn);
    DbCn.Open();
    DbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DbCn.Close();
}
```

And better, with parameters

```
public void Borrow_select(int intBorrow)
{
    string str_Query;
    str_Query = "UPDATE tbl_item SET no_of_available_item = no_of_available_item + @int_result WHERE id = @myID";
    DbCmd = new MySqlCommand(str_Query, DbCn);
    DbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@int_result", int_result);
    DbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myID", myID);
    DbCn.Open();
    DbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DbCn.Close();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but when i do this, there an error occurred says "Connection must be valid and open."

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
 public void DisplayProfile()
{
 string str_Query;
str_Query = "UPDATE tbl_item SET no_of_available_item = no_of_available_item 
+ @int_result WHERE id = @myID";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conn))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str_Query , connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Check is the reader has any rows at all before starting to 
                read.
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                // Read advances to the next row.
                while (reader.Read())
                {

              int ID = 
               reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("no_of_available_item"));



                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(ID ))
                    {

                   int_result = no_of_available_item - ID ;
           UppdateMethod(int_result );
                }}}}

   public void UppdateMethod(int int_result )
  {
    string str_Query;
     str_Query = "UPDATE tbl_item SET no_of_available_item = 
    no_of_available_item + @int_result WHERE id = @myID";
   cmd= new MySqlCommand(str_Query, connection);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@int_result", int_result);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myID", myID);
    connection.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connection.Close();}
```